# How to limit the number of categories in a pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below generates a pie chart by AlertTypeId. However, there are too many AlertTypeId and I'd like to limit the number of slices in the pie to the X most frequent alert and the rest goes into an "Other" category. How can I do that with ggplot2?

```
a = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
b = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
c = c(1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3)
sa2 = data.frame(WeekOfYear = a, UrgentState = b, AlertTypeId = c, IsUrgent = b)

ggplot(sa2, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(AlertTypeId))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Comment: This is not a ggplot issue, you will have to categorize your data prior to passing to any plotting function.

Comment: you'll need to process the data beforehand and determine whatever threshold you want for creating your 'other bucket'

Comment: There is [one sure way](https://blogs.oracle.com/experience/entry/pie_charts_just_dont_work_when_comparing_data_-_number_10_of_top_10_reasons_to_never_ever_use_a_pie) to limit the slices in a pie...

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to go about it, but the basic idea is that you need to

1. identify which AlertId's you want to select. This involves counting the number of rows per id.
2. send to `ggplot` a data.frame (or data.table) containing only those rows that you want to plot.

Here is an example using `data.table`:

#### Edit: *I broke this up into multiple lines to make it easier to follow*

```
library(data.table)
sa2.DT <- data.table(sa2, key="AlertTypeId")

# we can count the rows per id, by taking the length of any other column
ATid.Counts <-  sa2.DT[, list(AT.count=length(UrgentState)), by=AlertTypeId]

# then order Id's by their counts.  We will then take the `head( )` 
#    of this vector to identify the group being kept  
ATid.Ordered <- ATid.Counts[order(AT.count, decreasing=TRUE), AlertTypeId]
```

`ATid.Ordered` is the list of Ids ordered by their frequency count.
Taking `head(ATid.Ordered, n)`  will give the top `n` many of those.
Since we had set the key to `sa2.DT` as these Ids, we can therefore use 
the ordered list (or a portion of it) to subset the `data.table`

```
# select only those rows which have an AlertTypeId in the top n many
dat <- sa2.DT[.(head(ATid.Ordered, n=3)) ]  # <~~ note the dot in `.( )`
```

`dat` is the `data.table` (or `data.frame`) that we will use in `ggplot`

```
# use that selection to plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(AlertTypeId))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image: Pie Chart]